# what software can i use to access SILC Networks?

Tags: networking, internet, security, encryption, privacy

i want to access a SILC network  <strike>and all the infos from the [official site](http://silcnet.org/) are missing (site down?!?)</strike> 
EDIT: it seems the site is back up as of last week.
Good thing that i got curious and checked it again ..

so what software (still) exists to access a SILC network ?

also as complimentary questions:

- do you have infos on publicly accessible SILC servers ?
- what software can one use to run a SILC server ? <strike>(i ask since the main website is down)</strike>

Comment: I'm not familiar with that acronym, are you referring to this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SILC_(protocol%29 ?

Comment: this is indeed what i'm referring to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the website is now back up i will answer the complementary questions i asked for other users who tried to answer at an earlier time.

So the list of publicly accessible servers is available [here](http://silcnet.org/network/servers/).

And the software to run a SILC server is available [here](http://silcnet.org/software/download/server/) and more importantly,the server configuration manual is available [here](http://silcnet.org/docs/silc-server-config.html).

Hopefully the webserver is up again for a good while more !

Comment: For those who are curious of this protocol.. It is similar to irc in functionality,but albeit more secure..

Answer (score 1):

The main website is down but the [key exchange](https://silc.silcnet.org/) and [git repos](http://git.silcnet.org/gitweb/) still seems to be up, so it's probably just temporary. For other servers, Wikipedia [has a list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SILC_%28protocol%29#SILC_networks)

As far as I can tell, all the original software for SILC is abandoned with no "real" activity for about five years... But there are old versions of [the kopete plugin](http://silc.brokenpipe.de/) available on their website, and the official" server and clients are available from the repos:

```
ibid - easily extensible Python IM bot for IRC, Jabber, SILC, campfire, etc.
irssi-plugin-silc - SILC plugin for irssi
silc - transitional package for the SILC client
silcd - server for the SILC protocol
```

`silc` there is just a metapackage for the `irssi` plugin.

I've just read that Pidgin supports SILC so that might be the nicest modern option for you.

Comment: temporary for the last 2-3 months ? it's been that long since the site was down.. 
ibid is interesting,irssi i dont like at all,silcd i didnt know 
thanks for your input

Comment: the key exchange is down on my end..

Comment: i know of the servers from the wikipedia entry.. i meant other than those :)